# MVVM Light: Using DataService to retrieve database items

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm-light

I am working on a sample MVVM Light project and am implementing the SimpleIoc ViewModelLocator.  I have been able to construct a IRepositoryService that retrieves information from a database (i.e., Company, Employee, etc.) and stores the info into an ObservableCollection.  The IRepositoryService then returns the ObservableCollection to the ViewModel.  Here is how this is implemented:

```
public interface IRepositoryService
{

    void GetCompanies(Action<ObservableCollection<Company>, Exception> callback);

    void GetEmployees(Action<ObservableCollection<Employee>, Exception> callback);

}


class RepositoryService : IRepositoryService
{
    public void GetCompanies(Action<ObservableCollection<Company>, Exception> callback)
    {
        using (var context = new SidekickEntities())
        {
            var _companies = from co in context.Companies
                             select co;
            callback(new ObservableCollection<Company>(_companies), null);
        }
    }

    public void GetEmployees(Action<ObservableCollection<Employee>, Exception> callback)
    {
        using (var context = new SidekickEntities())
        {
            var _employees = from co in context.Employees
                             select co;
            callback(new ObservableCollection<Employee>(_employees), null);
        }

    }
}
```

The RepositoryService is then used in the ViewModel as such:

```
   public sealed class CompanyViewModel : ViewModelBase  //, IPageViewModel
    {
        private readonly IRepositoryService _dataService;
        private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the CompanyViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public CompanyViewModel(IRepositoryService dataService)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("CompanyViewModel DataService Constructor");
            try
            {
                _dataService = dataService;
                CompanyList = new ObservableCollection<Company>();
                _dataService.GetCompanies(
                    (companies, error) =>
                    {
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        CompanyList = companies;
                    }
                );

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }


        public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
        {
            get
            {
                return _companyList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_companyList == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _companyList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(CompanyListPropertyName);
            }

        }

    }
```

This all works great and allows me to display the data in a DataGrid, but I would like to know what is the method used to save changes back to the database?

For instance, if I added the following to the end of the CompanyViewModelConstructor() how would I save the new list back to the database?  I am using Entity Framework 5.x to access the database.

```
CompanyList.Add(new Company(-1, "Chipotle", "1400 High Street", "", "Columbus", "OH", "43235"));
```

Comment: Just add object(s) to your ObservableCollection (or modify existing objects) and once the save command is triggered one way or another itterate through the objects in the ObservableCollection and update or insert as needed. Obviously you'd want to add those methods to your IRepositoryService since you're already using that to fetch your records...

Comment: I would create a view model with commands for edit and add. This way everything is contained in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of one of my viewmodels

```
class YearModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members

    Year _year;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public Year Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
    }

    public Int32 id
    {
        get { return Year.id; }
        set
        {
            Year.id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    public String Code
    {
        get { return Year.Code; }
        set
        {
            Year.Code = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Code");
        }
    }

    public String Description
    {
        get { return Year.Description; }
        set
        {
            Year.Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get { return Year.DateCreated; }
        set
        {
            Year.DateCreated = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateCreated");
        }
    }

    public Int32 CreatedByID
    {
        get { return Year.CreatedByID; }
        set
        {
            Year.CreatedByID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreatedByID");
        }
    }

    public String CreatedByDesc
    {
        get { return Year.CreatedByDesc; }
        set
        {
            Year.CreatedByDesc = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreatedByDesc");
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateEdited
    {
        get { return Year.DateEdited; }
        set
        {
            Year.DateEdited = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateEdited");
        }
    }

    public Int32 EditedByID
    {
        get { return Year.EditedByID; }
        set
        {
            Year.EditedByID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EditedByID");
        }
    }

    public String EditedByDesc
    {
        get { return Year.EditedByDesc; }
        set
        {
            Year.EditedByDesc = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EditedByDesc");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public YearModel()
    {
        this._year = new Year
        {
            id = 0,
            Code = "",
            Description = "",
            DateCreated = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00),
            CreatedByID = 0,
            CreatedByDesc = "",
            DateEdited = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00),
            EditedByID = 0,
            EditedByDesc = ""
        };
    }

    #endregion

    #region Property Change Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public ICommand EditCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(EditYear); }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(AddYear); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Functions

    public void EditYear()
    {
        try
        {

            Service1Client service = new Service1Client();

            Year y = new Year();
            y.id = this.id;
            y.Code = this.Code;
            y.Description = this.Description;
            y.DateEdited = DateTime.Now;
            y.EditedByID = (Int32)Application.Current.Resources["UserID"];


            service.EditYear(y);
            MessageBox.Show("Your Year was edited successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logError le = new logError();
            le.log(ex, "YearViewModel", "EDIT");
        }
    }

    public void AddYear()
    {
        try
        {
            Service1Client service = new Service1Client();

            Year y = new Year();
            y.Code = this.Code;
            y.Description = this.Description;
            y.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            y.CreatedByID = (Int32)Application.Current.Resources["UserID"];
            y.DateEdited = this.DateEdited;


            service.AddYear(y);
            MessageBox.Show("Your new Year was entered successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logError le = new logError();
            le.log(ex, "YearViewModel", "ADD");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

```
<Button Content="Save New" 
  DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewYear}" 
  Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}"/>


class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    Action action;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
    {
        action = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```